# catching Face not found in EigenFaceRecognizer?

Tags: java, opencv

I need to catch the exception when face is not available in training image-set. I am using  EigenFaceRecognizer for recognition and when I run this if the image available it will predict it right, but if the image is not available it does not do anything, it predicts the last image in the training image set. How can I implement the code to give me error when the face is not available in the image set?

```
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(testImage);
System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);    
return predictedLabel;
```

Comment: Which java package and version of opencv are you using?

Comment: @ WillShackleford JDK 1.8.0_31 and OpenCV 2.4.10

Comment: Did you build OpenCV from source or did you download prebuilt binaries like https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
final double MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.01; // experiment with this.
int labela[] = new int[1];
double confidence[] = new double[1];
faceRecognizer.predict(testImage,labela, confidence);
int predictedLabel = (confidence[0] > MIN_CONFIDENCE)?labela[0]:-1; 
System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
```

You will need to experiment with the value of confidence you get back to find a good value that rejects failures without rejecting some legitimate cases.

Answer (score -1):

You are not very far from getting it right. You could do it this way instead.

```
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
int predictedLabel = -1;
predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(testImage);
System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);    
return predictedLabel;
```

Such that if after prediction and predictedLabel still gives you -1 you know the image was not predicted from your training image set.

If predictedLabel  returns 1 you know the image was predicted from your training image set. I am assuming you entered 1 as the label for images you added to your training set.

Comment: thanku sir bt no it dosent work still getting the same result it dosent print -1

Comment: What does it print? predictedLabel  should only change if the test image was predicted otherwise it will remain to be -1 if the image was not predicted i.e found in your training set.

Comment: it print the label of last image on the training image set but dosent print the -1